# Распознание параметров датчика с видео Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, распознавание

Имеется некий датчик, параметры которого нужно считывать с видеозаписи. Какие есть средства распознавания видео-фото в Linux по заданным заранее параметрам? Например определить положение стрелки, или уровень градусника?

Comment: пример прибора будет?
разобрать и покрасить прибор можно?

Comment: это слишком абстрактно. Приведите пример разных изображений и какую конкретно информацию вы хотите с них получить.

Comment: @jfs к примеру градусник, или индикатор давления со стрелкой, и конечно электросчётчик. Мне нужен некий готовый конструктор который можно настраивать графически для определения значений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На изображении результат работы программы по стрелке на тестере.
Сама программа на MatLab и подробности на Cuberforum.
Информацию можно найти по запросу "Оптический ввод информации с тестера (WEB)".

Там и картинок больше.

Если подробней про математику.

С WEB камеры делаются захваты и анализируется изображение.

Распознавание стрелки производится преобразованием Хафа, которое находит прямые линии в изображении.

Чтобы уменьшить предъявленную преобразованию информацию, применили контролируемое временное незначительное перемещение стрелки, например входным коммутатором.
Затем берем разность изображений и стрелки становятся виднее.

Можно даже подавать калиброванные напряжения, измерить преобразованием Хафа углы, тогда и шкала не нужна.

Или изменять калиброванное напряжение до совмещения стрелок.

Все зависит от конкретики применения.

Калиброванные, изменяемые программно постоянные напряжения до 5 вольт постоянного тока, (может даже переменного) можно получить на дешевых внешних звуковых картах, подключаемых к USB, там даже иногда конденсатор на выходе забывают поставить.

Для тестера, градаций выходного напряжения со звуковой карты   должно хватить с избытком. Напряжение задается двумя байтами.

Преобразование Хафа проводит отрезки по всем предъявленным точкам и затем в массиве проводится голосование. Если отрезки имеют одинаковый угол, будет большой всплеск в массиве.

---

С термометрами тоже можно применить временный подогрев, чтобы облегчить фильтрацию информации.

---

Там же есть пример с цифровым тестером. Изображение тестера нормализуется по размеру. Т.е уже примерно знаем где расположены сегменты.
Дальше выбираем информацию поперек сегмента тестера и ищем выпуклости в полученном массиве. Выпуклость определяется коэффициентом при второй степени разложения.
Если сегмент тестера не включен, в идеале будет ноль выпуклости.

---

Все сложно, но по другому?

Answer (score 0):

Делать скриншоты и попиксельно распознавать положение стрелки для аналоговых приборов, или распознавать цифры на экранах цифровых измерителей. Цифры можно ocr-ом распознавать

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Свет может меняться, появляться - исчезать блики, стрелка в течении времени может выглядеть иначе, изображение может двигаться. Потому предполагаю что нужно уметь распознавать заявленные образы и определять их положение, а это уже сложнее. Распознавать цифры скорее всего нет необходимости, однако прежде нужно определить их положение, возможно произвести какую то цветовую коррекцию. Вот и думаю что возможно есть инструмент позволяющий автоматизировать рутинные операции.

Comment: какой вопрос - такой и ответ)